# What is going on with my GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio

So I wanted to try out my Raspberry 3B+ once again, but I have been sitting here for hours without even being able to turn on a LED.

My code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(4,True)
time.sleep(5000)
GPIO.output(4,False)
```

and here is a picture of the guide I was following, and my connection is the same as his:

[image: Raspberry Pi Connection]

I wonder if you guys know why it doesn't work? This is in Python because that was what I used to do.

But I also tried Raspberry Pi out with Pi4J in Java - and there the code ran and all but I couldn't get any power from the GPIO pins and that seems to be the case here as well?

I could use all the help I can get! Thanks!

*Edited: I use WinSCP to transfer specific files to my raspberry (I used it for the Java part, shouldn't have an affect) and I usually connect to my Raspberry through my VNC Viewer

I would also like to say that when I tried multiple GPIO pins to debug it I found that in pin 3 ( 2 SDA ) I didnt even have to put it to HIGH for it to light the LED up? I dont know why this happened, what I've read it shouldn't have done that?

I'll go ahead and check it once again tomorrow but this is just an update to the issue! Thank you!

*2nd Update:

I did a "gpio readall" during the run - this is the result - keep in mind that I switched to BCM 4!

When I switched to BCM 4 it had a very low voltage but it light up, without me even activating it? And when I set it to false it doesnt turn off - so something is weird here

[image: GPIO readall]

Pictures (no resistor in this one):

[image: pic1]

[image: Pic2]

[image]

[image: failure]

Comment: Have you tried turning the LED around - it will only work the correct way round.

Comment: GPIO18 is also used for SPI have you got that turned on in Raspberry Pi Configuration, Interfaces? https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin12_gpio18

Comment: What happens if you connect your red wire to pin#1 (3.3v)? What's the value of that resistor (can't see the stripes in enough detail)? @CoderMike pin#18 is only used for SPI1 (which needs special set-up).

Comment: @CoderMike Hey! So I haven't tried that but I made sure to connect the GPIO pin to the longer part of the LED (the anode?) and Ground to the other one! I also dont know what SPI is but I tried different GPIO pins and it didnt work :/

Comment: @Dougie So I did that and it turned on, the hardware part seems to be working - which means that the software might be the issue? I'll add some info in the question

Comment: We need a photo of **YOUR** connections.

Comment: There you go @joan

Comment: You need a resistor, otherwise the LED might burn out.  Pin 3 and 5 (GPIO 2 and 3) have pull-ups to 3V3 fitted which is why the LED would light.  GPIO 4 (pin 7) has weak internal pulls to 3V3 enabled by default which will weakly light a LED.

Comment: Which GPIO pin should I use then? Because nothing seems to work, and how much Ohms would you recommend? Or do I have to calculate that with Ohms law?

Comment: Use a 200 to 400 ohm resistor.  Use GPIO 4 (pin 7).  Double check with https://pinout.xyz/ .  If the LED doesn't light when the GPIO is high swap the LED legs.

Comment: @joan Doesnt work, still the same issue.. When I connect it it light up (very very low power though) and when I run the program nothing happens..

Comment: It says "RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use all the time though - but that used to happen in the past as well.

Comment: Okay, try another tack.  Start (my) pigpio daemon. `sudo pigpiod`.  Then set GPIO 4 high `pigs w 4 1`, check the value `pigs r 4`.  Set GPIO 4 low `pigs w 4 0`, check the value `pigs r 4`.

Comment: @joan this is just blowing my mind lol, I will update the post with the picture. Both values are 0

Comment: Just check that the 1-wire bus is not enabled in `/boot/config.txt` That uses GPIO 4.  Perhaps do [gpiotest](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Shell_gpiotest)

Comment: @joan I made sure to disable 1-wire which was in sudo raspi-config?

Comment: I ran the gpiotest and got all failures

Comment: Why is GPIO BCM 4 turned on when I am doing nothing? How do I turn it off? Because others dont have that happen to them?

Comment: This so-called Question keeps changing. Make up your mind what you actually have and ask a proper question, and don't keep changing detail.

Comment: Its still the same question - no question is perfect. None of my GPIO ports work, none. And some of them have a default voltage of 3. And I keep digging around and I am trying to find a solution and I am giving as much info as possible. And I think one reason might be this GPIO BCM 4 port. And if you read all my information and all comments you can see that we are still discussing the same topic. I am just asking things that have to do with my issue - nothing wrong with that. Only because I ask why my BCM 4 GPIO pin does a specifik thing that isn't the same thing as switching question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but a guideline to help debug this, and future projects.

Your project consists of 2 parts, software and hardware, either or both may have problems.

The rest of us would debug this in 2 steps.

You could check the pin output with a multimeter or with software like `gpio readall`.
You may want to change the time to make this easier.

You could check the operation of the circuit; in this case (as Dougie suggested) connect the red wire to 3.3V.

Comment: Hey there Milliways! Thanks for the instructions! So I debugged a long time and I tried checking the voltage and I got nothing when I tried that - I can try it again tomorrow! As I commented above I tried using the 3.3V output and the LED light up! So the hardware part shouldn't be the issue.. I personally think I activate the wrong GPIO!